# tail-chaining of Interrupts

Tags: embedded, arm, interrupt

what is tail chaining of Interrupts which is supported by NVIC in ARM Cortex M3.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Tail-chaining is back-to-back processing of exceptions without the
>   overhead of state saving and restoration between interrupts. The
>   processor skips the pop of eight registers and push of eight registers
>   when exiting one ISR and entering another because this has no effect
>   on the stack contents.
>   [Cortex™-M3 Technical Reference Manual](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0337e/Babjagdg.html)

Which basically means, handling pending interrupts without repeating the stacking.

I recommend this book if you want to know more details:

[The Definitive Guide to the ARM Cortex-M3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0750685344)

Answer (score 3):

If an exception is in pending state when another exception handler has been completed, instead of returning to the interrupted program and then entering the exception sequence again, a tail-chain scenario will occur, where the processor will not have to restore all register values from the stack and push them back to the stack again. The tail-chaining of exceptions allows lower exception processing overhead and better energy efficiency.