# STM32 HAL GPIO interrupt count too much

Tags: c, interrupt, stm32, gpio, hal

I've got the following problem:
I've got 2 inputs on my electronic board:

```
#define TOR1_IN_uC_Port         GPIOC
#define TOR1_IN_uC_Pin          GPIO_PIN_5
#define TOR2_IN_uC_Port         GPIOE
#define TOR2_IN_uC_Pin          GPIO_PIN_6
```

I've got this initialisation:

```
GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING_FALLING;
GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = TOR1_IN_uC_Pin;
HAL_GPIO_Init(TOR1_IN_uC_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);
GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = TOR2_IN_uC_Pin;
HAL_GPIO_Init(TOR2_IN_uC_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI9_5_IRQn, 2, 1);
HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI9_5_IRQn);
```

I've got theses two functions for interruption:

```
void EXTI9_5_IRQHandler(void)
{
    if(__HAL_GPIO_EXTI_GET_IT(TOR1_IN_uC_Pin) != RESET)
    {
        HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(TOR1_IN_uC_Pin);
        __HAL_GPIO_EXTI_CLEAR_IT(TOR1_IN_uC_Pin);
    }
    if(__HAL_GPIO_EXTI_GET_IT(TOR2_IN_uC_Pin) != RESET)
    {
        HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(TOR2_IN_uC_Pin);
        __HAL_GPIO_EXTI_CLEAR_IT(TOR2_IN_uC_Pin);
    }
}

void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
{
    if (GPIO_Pin == TOR1_IN_uC_Pin)
        Input1.Count++;
    else if (GPIO_Pin == TOR2_IN_uC_Pin)
        Input2.Count++;
}
```

I've pluged on the inputs a GBF at 10Hz, but the counters counts too much.
When I print the counters on the serial port, it shows about 5kHz

When I read manually the state of the inputs, I can't verify if the input count too much.

Comment: What is TOR4_IN_uC_Pin? I only see definitions for 1 and 2.

Comment: It's a mismatch, I've corrected my post, thanks

Comment: Do some rubberducking and explain how your code works in detail. Maybe you want to add more code, it seems to me that there must be more code than you have shown. I am thinking of the link between HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler and HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback. Do you need to acknowledge/consume interrupts? A factor of 5kHz/10Hz seems less like an algorithm error (e.g. off-by-one), more like the maximum frequency a constantly looping ISR can print via serial... Is there something like a choice between edge-triggering and level-triggering?

Comment: What are you triggering on? Level? Then try what happens if you apply the non-triggering level constantly. Edge? Then try what happens when applying both levels constantly (i.e. no edges). If triggering on something else than level, reduce the input frequency. Does your count change with the frequency? Proportionally?

Comment: Apply some shielding, e.g. wrap everything in tin-foil (careful with making unintended contact of course). Does that recude the counts?

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem too, it took a while before I noticed it. It is because you clear the IRQ flag very close the interrupt return. Creating a [tail-chain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13029263/1850429) interrupt with itself.

```
void EXTI9_5_IRQHandler(void)
{
    if(__HAL_GPIO_EXTI_GET_IT(TOR2_IN_uC_Pin) != RESET)
    {
        HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(TOR2_IN_uC_Pin);
        __HAL_GPIO_EXTI_CLEAR_IT(TOR2_IN_uC_Pin);
    }
    __DMB(); // add this
}
```

You have to wait for the bus to finish the clear action. The [DMB instruction](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/CIHGHHIE.html) helps with this.

> Data Memory Barrier acts as a memory barrier. It ensures that all explicit memory accesses that appear in program order before the DMB instruction are observed before any explicit memory accesses that appear in program order after the DMB instruction. It does not affect the ordering of any other instructions executing on the processor.

Comment: It is a ridiculous answer. No barriers are needed to clear the interrupt flag. Please do not give wrong advices.

Comment: @PeterJ, not need no. You could also add a bunch of nops, or clear the flag first thing.

Comment: Flag should be cleared first. That is the rule of thumb. All barries should be considered as a necessary evil in a very specific circumstances (and definitely not in the simple interrupt routine).

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem, it was an electrical issue due to the R.C. circuit between the input and the micro GPIO.

The signal takes too much time to rise (signal in saw tooth). I changed my electronic and the mirco count very well now.

Comment: It is your solution. You can accept it. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) page helps you. You can not close it as in a simple forum.

Answer (score 0):

1. EXTI - always clear the IT flag first (other interrupts as well)
2. Switch will always generate more than one implulse.
3. HAL & EXTI - I had a lots of issues with it (maybe I am too lazy to learn this monstrous library) and started using bare registers - all problems had gone instantly :)